# Azure Data Movement no longer works

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Just upgraded several Azure libraries and now Azure Data Movement (E.g. TransferManager) no longer works.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement

Appears as though that package isn't using the latest changes from Microsoft.

Comment: What's the question?  You should open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: Have you tried to set up assembly binding redirects in app.config?

Comment: @NickGallant, the MS team is working on updating this library, and if the answer below is helpful, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 5/9:

this issue is fixed on the latest version [0.11.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement)

---

This is due to the changes in the latest version 10.0.0 of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` or `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File`.

You can nav to the [project site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Blob/Changelog.txt) of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, now the namespace is changing to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.* (for blob, it's Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob):

[image]

But in Data Movement library, the method `TransferManager.UploadAsync(myfile, destBlob)` is still refer to the type `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob` , which is now not available in v10.0.0 of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`.

[image]

So in Data Movement library -> TransferManager.UploadAsync(), the parameter should be changed to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob`. Then it can work well.

I see you have submitted an issue, and the team will fix the issue in Data Movement library soon.

As of now, you can use the lower version of Blob or File, and wait for the fix release(I also submit a bug for this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/169)).

Hope it helps.